# PowerMock mocks MoreAsserts

Tags: android, unit-testing, assert, powermock

I'm writing a unit test in android studio and using PowerMock

The test looks like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareOnlyThisForTest({Typeface.class})
public class ExtendedTextViewTest {

    ...

    @Test
    public void ctor_context_attributeSet_ShouldSetTypeface() throws Exception {
        // Act
        final LinkedList<Typeface> actualTypefaces = new LinkedList<Typeface>();
        ExtendedTextView textView = spy(new ExtendedTextView(contextMock, attributeSet) {
            @Override
            public void setTypeface(Typeface typeface) {
                actualTypefaces.add(typeface);
            }
        });

        // Assert
        MoreAsserts.assertEquals(new Typeface[]{typefaceMock}, actualTypefaces.toArray());
        verify(typedArrayMock, times(1)).recycle();
    }

}
```

When I run the test I get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method assertEquals in android.test.MoreAsserts not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.test.MoreAsserts.assertEquals(MoreAsserts.java)
    at com.loka.loka.common.ExtendedTextViewTest.ctor_context_attributeSet_ShouldSetTypeface(ExtendedTextViewTest.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
```

It seems that mockito mocks the MoreAsserts without me asking it to...what am I missing?

Thanks,
Slava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after searching I found the answer...
MoreAsserts is an android sdk class (android.test.MoreAsserts)

When running Unit Tests, the android sdk is not loaded, instead all the classes are stubbed with an implementation that throws exception, including MoreAsserts..

So I needed to replace the assertion with JUNit assert: Assert.assertArrayEquals

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Typeface[]{typefaceMock}, actualTypefaces.toArray());
```

Hope it will help you guys =]

Comment: Thanks. I just encountered same issue and was trying to find a replacement. It helps!